# msbuild - is there a way to specify not to build a website in a solution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, tfs, msbuild

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to create a build definition. Is there a way to specify somewhere in the build not to build the website in a solution?

I can manually tell it not to do that when I have the solution open (see below), but when I run the Build it errors out because the website won't build. But I don't need it to build.

[image]

Comment: How many projects are there in your solution? If you don't want to build the website project in the solution? Which things did you want to build? dll ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to build this project or sln in tfs build , you just need to remove it in the Build process parameters.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your solution file (.sln), remove the Build.0 entries. For example:

```
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "clientapp", "clientapp\", "{F49559D6-D6E7-43D9-8EB2-DE26496D5E63}"
```

Search for lines containing "Build.0" and the second UID and delete them.

```
{F49559D6-D6E7-43D9-8EB2-DE26496D5E63}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
```

The solution will load OK, but the website will not be built.

[ Thanks to [BmanMA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56191029/1978840) for this. ]