# Azure devops keeps building those projects that are set not to build in VS Configuration Manager

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I setting up a build in Azure devops.
My project is mvc application.
Visual studio 2019
Everything build fines except that I do not want to build one of my projects(It has some issues. I do not want to remove it so i checked it to not be built) and in the configuration Manger the **Build** check mark is not checked . But the devops keeps building it and it breaks my build. No issue in visual studio 2019. Not sure what to do . Here is my yml file
[image]Any help will be much appreciate it

Comment: I assume you unchecked build for `Release` configuration right? It may be a stupid question, but did you commit and push your changes? And for the future, if you use YAML pipelines please copy paste your code and use syntax highlighting instead of screenshot. It would be better :)

Comment: @user464291 Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

> But the devops keeps building it and it breaks my build.

For this issue, please check the following two points:

1.Whether the changes are committed and pushed to remote azure repo.

2.Since you're build with release+any cpu mode in CI pipeline, you must make sure you unchecked the Build box for Release+Any CPU page instead of Debug+Any CPU page.

[image]

[image]

In addition, Lance Li gave a detailed analysis about this issue in this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64148474/11508192), you can refer to it for details.

Answer (score 0):

I think in some of these project someone might have manully changed the project file or solution file.Beacuse using the configuration manager was not fixing the issue .So We had to remove all the project and set them up again