# directive or an assembly reference build errors with Cake

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cakebuild

When running .\build.ps1 I end up with the error

The type or namespace name 'TestProject1 ' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)[D:\Projects\TestProject1 .csproj]

```
Task("Build")
.Does(() =>
{
MSBuild("D:/Projects/Test.sln", settings =>
    settings.SetConfiguration(configuration));
});
```

"TestProject1" is an independent project in a solution. It does not referenced with the main or any other projects.

Does anyone have any suggestions? any MSBuild configuration settings to ignore such type of unreferenced project while building the solution using Cake script?

Comment: Does it build from inside the Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, it's building inside VS.

Comment: Plus one to your question then - no idea why it doesn't build with Cake... :(

Comment: Probably not a Cake issue, as Cake only calls out to msbuild.exe. Are you able to build the solution with msbuild.exe directly for the specific configuration?

Comment: you need to create build configuration without this project and use it in msbuild, [how to exclude project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778916/how-to-exclude-project-from-build-in-msbuild)