# is there a way in c# to #ifdef a whole folder

Tags: c#, conditional-compilation

I segregated my code into folders. So, instead of #ifdef-ing all the files in the folder, is there a way to #ifdef the folder itself? I looked online, but could not find anything obvious.

Comment: There is a supported way of doing so, although it is project-based, not folder-based (but then again, so is everything in the world of C#/.NET): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-exclude-projects-from-a-build#:~:text=On%20the%20menu%20bar%2C%20choose,and%20then%20rebuild%20the%20solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I exclude a project from a build in MSBuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778916/how-can-i-exclude-a-project-from-a-build-in-msbuild)